# NullPointerException when sending notification email by jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I configured Jenkins to send notification by email in case of error in build.

java: open jdk 11.0.11

maven: Apache Maven 3.0.5

jenkins: 2.277.4

mailer plugin: 1.34

This is the config:

Notification par email

Serveur SMTP:smtp.gmail.com

Nom d'utilisateur:email_adress

Mot de passe:my_password

Utiliser SSL

Port SMTP:465

When i send test email everything works fine.
When a build is unstable and the mailer is triggered i get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.toString(InternetAddress.java:472)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setAddressHeader(MimeMessage.java:733)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setFrom(MimeMessage.java:382)
at jenkins.plugins.mailer.tasks.MimeMessageBuilder.buildMimeMessage(MimeMessageBuilder.java:204)
at hudson.tasks.MailSender.createEmptyMail(MailSender.java:407)
at hudson.tasks.MailSender.createFailureMail(MailSender.java:274)
at hudson.tasks.MailSender.createMail(MailSender.java:182)
at hudson.tasks.MailSender.run(MailSender.java:112)
at hudson.tasks.Mailer.perform(Mailer.java:179)
at hudson.tasks.Mailer.perform(Mailer.java:142)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:803)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:752)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:177)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:697)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1932)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of your pipeline?

Comment: i used a simple freestyle project

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya Looks like an issue with the parameters used in the email step in your freestyle job, can you share that config?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting system admin email and see?
Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Jenkins Location -> System Admin e-mail address